# Jobs: Search / Tag by Technology

Tags: feature-request, jobs, organization

Would like jobs.stackoverflow.com to have the ability to tag/group by technologies. Existing browse feature requires me to click on each one before seeing whether it's PHP, .NET, Java, etc.

Ideally, this could be extended to feature or ignore based on my SO settings.

Comment: Totally agree with you, was just about to post a rant on meta about this. The list now contains 180+ jobs, and it would be so nice to be able to filter OUT all the php, java, python and other technologies I just don't do...